How to automatically open an Android notification from a `NotificationListenerService`?
I want to implement an Android application that intercept notifications generated by another app, and then automatially opens such notifications.
Currently, I have the interception part implemented, but the opening of the notification, which should be triggered by pendingIntent.send(), does not work:
package com.example.notificationinterceptor

import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification
import android.util.Log


class NotificationInterceptor : NotificationListenerService() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "NotificationInterceptor"
        const val TARGET_APP_PACKAGE = "com.example.notificationgenerator"
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got notification from ${sbn?.packageName}")
        sbn?.let {
            // Check if the notification comes from the desired app
            if (sbn.packageName == TARGET_APP_PACKAGE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Notification from ${TARGET_APP_PACKAGE} detected")

                // Get the notification's PendingIntent
                val notification = sbn.notification
                val pendingIntent = notification.contentIntent

                // Try to trigger the PendingIntent, which simulates clicking the notification
                try {
                    // **Here is where the notification is not opened**
                    pendingIntent.send()
                } catch (e: PendingIntent.CanceledException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to trigger notification: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


I point out that I am already able to intercept the posting of new notifications of the target app. The problem is that pendingIntent.send() seems not to take effect, while I expected that the app com.example.notificationgenerator would be opened. Moreover, if I click manually the notification, the target app is opened, so it is not the problem of the notification.
What am I doing wrong? How can I solve my problem? I do not want to use automation apps like Tasker or similar, I would like a programmatic solution).
